# $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ function has a finite moment?

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, moment-generating-functions

I have a function $u_0(x) \in H^1(\mathbb{R})$. It is nonnegative, compactly supported, and has a mass $M>0$.

I have to prove that its first moment is finite.

My attempt: $\int_{\mathbb{R}} xu_0(x) \leq (\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^2)^\frac{1}{2} (\int_{\mathbb{R}} u^2_0(x))^{\frac{1}{2}}$

We know that the $u_0$ term is finite because it is in $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ but about the first term I am unsure. My guess was that instead of integrating over $\mathbb{R}$, we would consider the support of $u_0$ which is compact. Thus, the first term evaluated over a compact support is finite, and that's enough?

Comment: yes, integrate over the compact support.

Comment: The set-up seems a little strange, because you can reach the same conclusion (avoiding typos and imprecisions...) for compactly-supported $u_o\in L^2$... Are you sure that this is the question?

Comment: @paulgarrett that's my mistake, I should not have framed it as such. $H^1$ regularity was only one feature of the function. I had just assumed that the answer maybe only has to do with it's regularity and my attempt was wrong.

Comment: @ali, ah, ok, good to understand this. Thanks for clarifying. :)